# Add extra tab like page/post in wordpress for categories/products

Tags: wordpress, tabs, admin, categories

I was wondering if there was any plugin or a way to add extra tab in Wordpress admin similar to page/post that would be called categories and inside of it have different categories + subcategories and inside them products? This is not an e-commerce site so I do not want to use woocommerce plugin...

It would look something like that:

Categories (Name of the tab) -> Category1 (ie. Tapes) -> SubCategory (ie. Isolating tapes-> Products

Would apprieciate any help! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Despite that you can't create menu item structure like that you've described in your admin area without some complicated coding, you can create custom post types & custom taxonomies for it.

So, you can have the structure like this one:

```
Products
- Products
- Product categories
```

You can make hierarchical categories list & assign any of it to any product.

Please refer to the codex on creation of the custom post & taxonomies

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

If you want the plugin, there are plenty of them. For example  you can use this one:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/